# Using many window.open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loop and need to open new window in a new tab many times:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
   window.open(item.url)
})
console.log("here") // Doesn't work
```

But window.open executes only 1 time.

Also other functions not executing.
What I supposed to do?

Comment: Of course not, I need to open many tabs and save main window @Spring

Comment: What does dosn't work mean re the console?

Comment: It means that function not executing @mmmmmm

Comment: Ah so the issue is not open only happening once - but that the program waits for you to act with the window -

Comment: How I should act? @mmmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'_blank'` as second param of [`window.open("url",'_blank');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

or set a specific window title for each item (prevent same because it'll open in same ):

```
items.forEach((item) => {
   // below I used url as title , if you have title attribute 
   // you can set item.title instead 
   window.open(item.url,item.url) 
})
```

For example try pasting below code in console , it should open 2 tabs :
check this in console :

```
[{"url":"http://www.google.com","title":"google"},{"url":"http://www.stackoverflow.com","title":"stackoverflow"}].forEach((item) => {
    window.open(item.url,'_blank')
    // or use 
    // window.open(item.url,item.title)
});
```

Comment: It opens 1 tab ... @Spring

Comment: I've tried ["http://www.google.com","http://www.stackoverflow.com"].forEach((item, idx) => {
    window.open(item,`_blank${idx}`)
}); and its the same result @Spring

Comment: if you use `"_blank"` no need to append index

Comment: I wanted to try specific windows, but, anyway, it not works @Spring

Comment: seems problem in your browser , works well from my side ! try exact example as posted to check if problem in browser

Comment: Okay, I think problem with the browser

Comment: but can you apologize what is wrong with google chrome? @Spring

Comment: @pavel , sorry , but I could not understand your last comment ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228356/discussion-between-spring-and-pavel).

Comment: to able to open multiple window, one need to allow pop-up in there browser setting

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution isn't working there might be the case where browser must be blocking pop-ups. Please allow that. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECw8b.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).